# For loop iteration does not have desired affect

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below code which scrapes a website, and writes the results to a csv file. The problem is that the for loop for some reason prints multiple copies of each iteration where it should only write each iteration once. Can someone please assist and point out what it is that I am missing here?
Thank you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://online.computicket.com'
home_page = requests.get(url)

home_page.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(home_page.content, 'lxml')


links = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'info'})

next_link = []

for link in links:
    next_link.append(link.get("href"))


for i in range(0, len(next_link),1):    
    next_link.append(i)
    print(url + next_link[i])
    new_url = requests.get(url + next_link[i])   

    for link in (url + next_link[i]):
        new_url.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(new_url.content, 'lxml')

        info_name = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'es-cost'}) 
        heading = soup.find('h1',{'class' : 'full'})

        with open('Don.csv', 'a') as csv_file:

            #csv_file.write(heading.get_text())
            for name in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'es-cost'}):
                csv_file.write(heading.get_text())
                csv_file.write(name.get_text())

                print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: don't understand this line
`for link in (url + next_link[i]):`
(url + next_link[i]) will be a string, and it is like
`for link in "some string":`
so there will be a write to the csv_file for every character in (url + next_link[i])

Comment: Good day. Thank you for your reply. Much appreciated. Also, I am new to python so I apologize if my question sounds silly. The purpose of the code you pointed out is this : I make a connection to the home page (eg https://online.computicket.com) , from there I find all the extension links to the pages that contain the data I want eg(/web/event/nba_africa_2018/1225212005/Show:Additional Info) . I then concatenate the home page + the extension, make a connection to the new url and start scraping the data. The problem seems to be that it writes the correct data for all links but multple times.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program prints multiple copies because of nested for loop. However, the `link` variable of it isn't used anywhere inside the loop. Try to remove nested for statement, replace this part of code:

```
for i in range(0, len(next_link),1):    
next_link.append(i)
print(url + next_link[i])
new_url = requests.get(url + next_link[i])   

for link in (url + next_link[i]):
    new_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new_url.content, 'lxml')

    info_name = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'es-cost'}) 
    heading = soup.find('h1',{'class' : 'full'})

    with open('Don.csv', 'a') as csv_file:

        #csv_file.write(heading.get_text())
        for name in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'es-cost'}):
            csv_file.write(heading.get_text())
            csv_file.write(name.get_text())

            print(name.get_text())
```

with this

```
for i in range(0, len(next_link),1):    
next_link.append(i)
print(url + next_link[i])
new_url = requests.get(url + next_link[i])   

new_url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(new_url.content, 'lxml')

info_name = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'es-cost'}) 
heading = soup.find('h1',{'class' : 'full'})

with open('Don.csv', 'a') as csv_file:

    #csv_file.write(heading.get_text())
    for name in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'es-cost'}):
        csv_file.write(heading.get_text())
        csv_file.write(name.get_text())

        print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, after modifying my code as per your suggestion, and also figuring out that the nested for loop was basically iterating over each character and writing the information to the file after each iteration, the code now has the desired results. Again. Very much appreciated.